# ADMob SDK cause weird error. Does anyone knows about what "_sqlite3_prepare_v3"is?

Tags: ios, sdk, admob, cocoapods

This error make me crazy.

[Error messages image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MuAE.png)

---

ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'VNGMoatMobileAppKit'

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

"_sqlite3_prepare_v3", referenced from:
 -[APMSqliteStore prepareSQL:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMSqliteStore_4b93d70f10ae469a3a03d3a4cf33073f.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

### clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

When i added ADMob SDK frameworks, build failed with above message

I already asked to Google Admob forum, but answers are not for me.

I'm applied SDK manually.
Our project is too old and has 4 targets. So pod can not set preferences automatically.

When i try to apply it to an empty project, no matter manually or pod anything works perfect.
But i'm trying to our project, it show error message.

I'm dying for this problem.

XCode Version : 11.3.1

OS Version : Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6

ADMob SDK version where the issue occurs(i tested) : 7.56.0, 7.57.0, 7.58.0

### Below messages are the pod messages

CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `OURPROJECT_Beta` to `Target Support Files/Pods-OURPROJECT_Beta/Pods-OURPROJECT_Beta.beta_debug.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-OURPROJECT_Beta/Pods-OURPROJECT_Beta.beta_debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Configuation/BETA.xcconfig`).

[!] The `OURPROJECT_Beta [RC_DEBUG]` target overrides the `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-OURPROJECT_Beta/Pods-OURPROJECT_Beta.rc_debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `OURPROJECT_Beta [RC_DEBUG]` target overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-OURPROJECT_Beta/Pods-OURPROJECT_Beta.rc_debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `OURPROJECT_Beta [RC_DEBUG]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-OURPROJECT_Beta/Pods-OURPROJECT_Beta.rc_debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

---